# No Apps to perform this acion - Dialog coming always

Tags: android

I am trying to communicate between two apps by sending a text message.
This is my first  app that contains a button which will invoke an action send so that all other apps with action SEND appears on this Dialog.

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1))
        .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(); 
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.putExtra("ComingFrom", "Activity 1");  
                final int result = 1;
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Sending File..."),result); 
            }
        });
```

Now this is my second application that will get the intent.

```
// Get the intent that started this activity
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri data = intent.getData();

if (intent != null) {
    // Figure out what to do based on the intent type
    if (intent.getType().indexOf("image/") != -1) {
        // Handle intents with image data ...
    } else if (intent.getType().equals("text/plain")) {
        // Handle intents with text ...
    }
}
```

this is my second application Manifest whihc contains the Action SEND.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

But the problem is I am not getting a dialog that shows my other application instead shows no application to perform this action.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also add a mimetype attribute inside your bundle when you launch your intent.

```
 intent.setType("text/plain");
```

for instance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the type with this for sending the text, image etc as type was mime type.

for simple text or plain text you need to use text/plain or for image you need to set image/*

if you attaching any image file or not then also it'll open default application in android

```
intent.setType("text/plain");
```

or for (using with image file sending)

```
intent.setType("image/*");
```